# LeaveApplyForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: django

I want to save a leave in database applied from employee but when i was submit i faced this error ----LeaveApplyForm' object has no attribute 'save'---

```
   **models.py**
    class All_Leaves(models.Model):
      leave_types = models.ForeignKey(Leave_Types, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="all_leave")
      user   = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="all_leave")
      reason = models.CharField(('Reason'), max_length=120)
      start_date = models.DateTimeField(('Start Date'),auto_now = True)
      end_date = models.DateTimeField(('End Date'),auto_now = True)

      class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("All Leave")
        verbose_name_plural = ("All Leaves")



    **View.py**
    def apply_leave(request):
        print("user",request.user)
        print("data",request.POST)
        leave_type_data = Leave_Types.objects.all()
        if request.method =="POST":
            form = LeaveApplyForm(request.POST, None)
            print("form status",form.is_valid())
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(leave_types=request.POST['leave_types'], user=request.user)
                print("form in")
                return render(request, 'dashboard.html',{"var_leave":"false","leave_type_data":leave_type_data})
            else:
                print("form errors",form.errors)
                return render(request, 'dashboard.html',{"var_leave":"false","leave_type_data":leave_type_data,"form":form})
```

**forms.py**
    class LeaveApplyForm(forms.Form):
        start_date = forms.DateTimeField(required=True, error_messages={'required': 'Please Choose Start Date.'})
        end_date = forms.DateTimeField(required=True, error_messages={'required': 'Please Select End Date.'})
        reason = forms.CharField(required=True, error_messages={'required': 'Please Enter Your Reason.'})

```
    class Meta:
        model = All_Leaves
        fields = ('start_date','end_date','reason')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've inherited from `forms.Form` instead of `forms.ModelForm`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your kind help.It works fine thank you so much